# Legal impact of authentication with DocuSign embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement Embedded signing using DocuSign. And I am wondering what is the legal meaning for the arguments AssertionID, AuthenticationInstant, AuthenticationMethod, and SecurityDomain when creating receiver view?

For example if I put "none" as authentication method and no value for other parameters does the signature still have legal value (in France in my case)?

Will DocuSign use signer IP address in the signature?
If I put some values, for how long should I keep this info in my app's database to stay in rules of e-signature legislation?

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/legality/global/france

Comment: Thanks. But it does not really answers the question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether an electronic signature meets the legal requirements for a signature or not is a legal question that you will want to discuss with the business people in your organization or company. They're paid to decide these types of issues and depending on the situation may decide to discuss with their legal counsel.

There are many different meanings to "legal signature" depending on the nature of the contract (does it involve real property?), the signatories, and the applicable laws.

For example, France is a "civil law" country. So electronic signatures for some use cases require an AES (Advanced Electronic Signature) or a QES (Qualified Electronic Signature). Good news is that DocuSign can also be used to create those types of signatures.

### Re: AssertionID, AuthenticationInstant, AuthenticationMethod, and SecurityDomain

These are optional data fields that you can supply to DocuSign. If you use them, they record additional details about how and when your application authenticated the signer.

With DocuSign embedded signing, your application can authenticate the signer and then DocuSign provides the signing ceremony. But later, if the signature is challenged, you will want to provide information about your authentication of the signer. That's what those fields are for.

### Re: if I put "none" as authentication method and no value for other parameters does the signature still have legal value?

If your application does not authenticate the signer, and you do not ask DocuSign to authenticate the signer, then the signature would have minimal legal value because there's no proof of who the signer was. But such signatures can still have a lot of value--remember that the vast majority of signatures are never challenged. So if the signer feels bound by their signature and your organization is willing to accept the signature, then all is well.

Note that your application can ask DocuSign to authenticate an embedded signer even if your application doesn't. For example, you can have DocuSign machine read the signer's French identity card and check the name on it. This is the [DocuSign Identity](https://www.docusign.com/products/identify) feature.

### Re: Will DocuSign use signer IP address in the signature?

Yes, we record the signer's IP address. But that is a very low level of signer authentication.

### If I put some values, for how long should I keep this info in my app's database to stay in rules of e-signature legislation?

That depends on your company's practices (and applicable laws and regulations) for its business records. Ask your business colleagues.

Comment: Thank you for an exhaustive answer.